# Document font substitution (LibreOffice, MS Office)

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, libreoffice

In my office we're having this little delicate problem that a brand image group has decided some changes in our graphical profile. One thing this leads to is the change of document fonts from "Times New Roman" to "Georgia".

This means we have hundreds of documents that we will need to change fonts in.

Now is there a way from the line or by a script doing the substitution of fonts either in Linux/Libreoffice or Windows/MS Office?

Perhaps something like:

```
for i in *.doc; do
  libreoffice --font-substitution input-font="Times New Roman" output-font="Georgia" newfiles/$i $i;
done
```

I hope you get the picture. A way to substitute fonts "en masse":-)

Thanks for your efforts!

/Paul

Comment: In Microsoft Office you could probably write something in Visualbasic and try to call that from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to concern before you even think of beginning this:
Word uses Styles for the text format. When you copy in some text from an other copy writer you will copy in there styles when you just use CTRL V.
Looking at you style sheet will show than loads of styles.

If this is the case your trick to change all in one go will NOT work

For this to work ALL your styles must be based on the normal style. Then all your texts must use styles whatever formatting you do. Just one single hand made font change will make this fail. It even can make that doc corrupt.

Another issue is that some styles are based on "None" placing them on the same level as the normal style. Each of these styles has to be changed. You could do this in VBA by asking each style on there format and than change it accordingly.

For myself. I would not do it. Take a document att a time. Talk with sales and product management on what are the most commonly used ones and start with them

Answer (score 0):

My version of LibreOffice have an option to replace a font by another, see: `Tools>Options...>LibreOffice>Fonts`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ngulam!

Your answer led me into looking further for command line solutions and now I got it!

Put a bunch of Officefiles (new compressed ones like DOCX, PPTX, ODT) in a directory. **Use copies. Don't run this on originals.** Then create and run the following Bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.*; do

unzip -d tmp $i
find tmp -type f | xargs sed -i 's/"Times New Roman"/Georgia/g'
# find tmp -type f | xargs sed -i 's/"&apos;Times New Roman&apos;"/"Georgia"/g'
cd tmp; zip -r ../$i .
rm -Rf tmp

done

exit0
```

When the script has completed the font "Times New Roman" has been substituted to "Georgia" in all files in the directory.

/Paul

PS! The second code line starting with "find" was necessary when substituting "Times New Roman" to "Georgia", but not when substituting for instance "Arial" to Georgia". It probably depends on the spaces within "Times New Roman".

Comment: Having some problems handling the spaces in "Times New Roman"....